# iOS Swift: SDWebImage Image Loading Error

Tags: swift, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImage to load images into a paginated horizontal collection view. Some images aren't loaded and give an  error "canceled."

Here is how I declare the cell:

```
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PHOTOS_CELL_ID, for: indexPath) as! PhotosCell
```

Here is how I load images into the cell's image view:

```
            cell.photoImgV.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:photo[Constants.PHOTO_URL] as! String), placeholderImage: nil, options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (img, err, cacheType, imgURL) in
            if err != nil{
                print("ERROR LOADING IMAGE: \(err?.localizedDescription ?? "ERRRRoR")")
            }
                // prints: ERROR LOADING IMAGE: cancelled
```

I hope there is a fix for that.

Comment: Can you show the line which you declare `cell`? I need to know `cell` is reused or not.

Comment: thanks, I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know how `SDWebImage` implement their [sd_setImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIView%2BWebCache.m#L67) methods. At the the beginning of methods, `sd_cancelImageLoadOperationWithKey` is called to cancel current request and start a request with new url.

[image]

In your situation, I guess error is logged because cells are reused.

When a cell is displayed on screen, it starts a request to fetch image by using `sd_setImage`. Before this request is completed, you scroll and make this cell move out of screen. At this moment, you continue to scroll and cell is reused. `sd_setImage` is called again on this cell with another url while current request isn't completed. And as I said above, `sd_setImage` cancels current request before starting a new request.

*`cancelled` error is logged because `sd_cancelImageLoadOperationWithKey` is called at the beginning of `sd_setImage` method.*

You shouldn't care about `cancelled` error in this situation. Your code is running right way.

Comment: Awesome! So does that mean the app won't crash if I loaded the images without checking if there is an error?

Comment: Sure, I always use it with a nil block ;)